# How to get nuget for linux based docker container

Tags: docker, nuget-package, azure-aks, linux-containers

I am trying to dockerrize the .NET core application which is having internal dependency with NuGet to fetch some libraries/dependencies.
I am using Linux based docker containers as AKS do not support windows based nodes (Please correct me if I am wrong with this - AKS do not support windows based nodes).

I am trying to fetch the NuGet for Linux based docker images, after searching for help I got this information-https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/3390
Which says that NuGet support is not available for Linux based docker containers.

```
mcr.microsoft.com/windows AS installer
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$= 'Stop'; $= 'SilentlyContinue';"]
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile nuget.exe https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe
ARG PAT
```

This is just a sample docker file for Windows based container to fetch the NuGet.

I want to achieve same with Linux based docker container

Comment: windows nodes are not supported in aks, but they are available in preview (which I pointed out already in your previous question, which you didnt accept, btw).

Comment: @4c74356b41 If windows based container support is in preview, then are we supposed to start using them? If yes, can you please help me with the correct configuration/resources which should I refer.
Because the configuration that I used is not working with windows, I switched to Linux based containers. With Linux based containers, I am facing issue with dockerization- How to get nuget packages for Linux docker containers. :(